# Magento Quick Simple Product Creation stuck on Please wait… screen

Tags: javascript, magento

When I have a configurable product, I can't create `associate products` through the Quick simple product creation menu because the screen gets stuck on the `loading Please wait...` screen. It doesn't matter how long I wait, the `simple product` will not be created.

I thought at first it was maybe a JavaScript thing, so I removed all the JavaScript from the server and uploaded the JavaScript from a fresh install (1.7.0.2 version) but still the problem persists.

When I create a `simple product` normally I can assign it fine, but it would be quicker and less error-prone if we could add simple products through the quick simple product creation menu.

Anyone have any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Since your question is not about magento development, your question is best suited for http://magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: I did post it there but noone replied, so I thought I would try here..

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things you need to look into.

1. **Check www vs. no www redirects:** Your site has to be accessible by any one of them. Not both ways. Double check .htaccess & under cPanel.
2. **mod_security:** This is another cause why Magento is stuck on 'Please Wait' when adding products or updating them. Disable it & see problem is solved. You might want to contact server admin to have Rules whitelist your Magento Admin backend.